# Doctrine many to many + join table request failing

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a `server` entity with this field who has a `ManyToMany` relation + `joinColumns` options

```
/**
 * @var User[]|ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="servers")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="server_owner",
 *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")},
 *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="owner_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $owners;
```

I am trying to find a `server` by `owner` so in my controller I made this request

```
$user = $this->getUser()->getId();
$servers = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Server')->findBy([
    'owners' => $user,
]);
```

But during the execution I get this error

> "An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, #all other fields# FROM server t0 WHERE server_owner.owner_id = ?' with params [1]:\n\nSQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'server_owner.owner_id' in 'where clause'"

This request should work, right ?

I don't understand why this don't find the `server_owner.owner_id` column.

Is this a problem with my doctrine request ?
What did I do wrong / can modify ?

Comment: Do you have a relation to servers in the User entity as well? If so couldn't you just do `$servers = $user->getServers()`

Comment: Yes this is working, I didn't think to this before... Thanks